# Visual Studio vertical scrollbare width

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Suddenly the scrollbar of the code window in visual studio has a larger width than it should be.

Compare the width in the image on top and the one on the bottom (that is normal)

I can't find an option to change the width, so please help me, where can i change that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **Match Margin** from Productivity Power Tools. You can turn it off in Options - Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: in my case this was not the answer because I didn't have Productivity Power Tools installed. Fixed my problem by reinstalling Visual Studio...